# How to initialize an empty byte array in Solidity?

Tags: solidity

I need to pass an empty byte array to a function derived from **OpenZeppelin**:

```
function mintTo(address to, uint256 tokenId, uint256 amount) 
{
    bytes memory data;
    _mint(to, tokenId, amount, data);
}
```

However, although this code compiles and works perfectly, **Slither** is complaining that this is

> is a local variable never initialized

I'm curious how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shut slither up or just use an empty string:

```
_mint(to, tokenId, amount, "");
```